# Add or remove rows dynamically from HTML table upon click

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code to add rows dynamically upon click:

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
            counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
            counter + '"/></td></tr>');
        jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
    });
});
</script>
<table class="authors-list">
<tr>
    <td>author's first name</td><td>author's last name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>
```

The code works fine in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), but when I copy it to my notepad, and try to run it from the WAMP server, it doesn't work.

Another question: how can I add a remove row button beside each row in order to remove the row upon click?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: did you include a script reference to jQuery?

Comment: it's just not adding the row when I click on "Add Author"

Comment: Please open the developer console built into your browser, and report what errors are shown.

Comment: If you add a button to a <td> tag you can use <button onclick="jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();">Remove</button> to remove the row

Comment: I've copied as it is into a <body> and checked via Apache and it is working. The js include should be missing...

Comment: @CrazyTrain I don't know how

Comment: @CrazyTrain
Ok it says Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your second question (with slightly changed code):

```
$(function() {

    var $table = $('table.authors-list'),
        counter = 1;

    $('a.add-author').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        var newRow = 
            '<tr>' + 
                '<td><input type="text" name="first_name' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="last_name' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><a class="remove">remove</a></td>'
            '</tr>';
        $table.append(newRow);
    });

    // Remove rows on click
    $table.on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YsgEL/

So the best way to remove rows is to listen click events on some `remove`-links and delete corresponding parent row.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you have loaded JQuery correctly into your HTML file? JQuery could be loaded in JSFilde already but is maybe missing on your Project.

Comment: No I'm not sure, how can I load it?

Comment: Put the following in your HTML Header (betweeen `<head>` and `</html>`) and check if it's working.
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Do you know how to add a delete row button?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line of code before your `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will load the jQuery library into your web page, letting you use all the functions and properties of `jQuery` or `$` object.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your first question:**
Please provide us with further information... This problem can be caused by several reasons.

**Answer to your second question:**
You can append a remove button with class "remove_button" to your variable called "newRow" and add an ID to it (i.e `id="remove_button_" + counter`).

When clicking on the remove button call a function which is extracting the number of the button's ID and remove the other elements with same number by using `remove()` function